# What is HibernateTemplate class?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new in Hibernate currently want to implement the Hibernate Template  classes , any one please tell me about the Hibernate Template classes.

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="mnrpass" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>employee.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="springHibernateExample" class="com.javarticles.spring.hibernate.SpringHibernateExample">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Spring’s HibernateTemplate provides an abstract layer over a Hibernate Session. It converts Hibernate-specific exceptions to one of the Spring’s unchecked data-access exception.
It also provides many convenience methods that help you in querying and persisting objects.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Copied from Hibernate Interview Questions:](http://www.journaldev.com/3633/hibernate-interview-questions-and-answers#hibernatetemplate-class)

> **Hibernate Template**
>
> When Spring and Hibernate integration started, Spring ORM provided two
>   helper classes – `HibernateDaoSupport` and `HibernateTemplate`. The reason
>   to use them was to get the `Session` from Hibernate and get the benefit
>   of Spring transaction management. However from Hibernate 3.0.1, we can
>   use `SessionFactory getCurrentSession()` method to get the current
>   session and use it to get the spring transaction management benefits.
>   If you go through above examples, you will see how easy it is and
>   that’s why we should not use these classes anymore.
>
> One other benefit of HibernateTemplate was exception translation but that can be achieved easily by using `@Repository` annotation with
>   service classes, shown in above spring mvc example. This is a trick
>   question to judge your knowledge and whether you are aware of recent
>   developments or not.

Answer (score 3):

**HibernateTemplate** is a helper class that is used to simplify the data access code. This class supports automatically converts HibernateExceptions which is a checked exception into DataAccessExceptions which is an unchecked exception. HibernateTemplate is typically used to implement data access or business logic services. The central method is execute(), that supports the Hibernate code that implements HibernateCallback interface.
Define HibernateTemplate.

org.springframework.orm.hibernate.HibernateTemplate is a helper class which provides different methods for querying/retrieving data from the database. It also converts checked HibernateExceptions into unchecked DataAccessExceptions.

**HibernateTemplate benefits :**

1. HibernateTemplate simplifies interactions with Hibernate Session.
2. The functions that are common are simplified to single method calls.
3. The sessions get automatically closed.
4. The exceptions get automatically caught and are converted to runtime exceptions.

Visit this link for the proper example

http://www.javarticles.com/2015/04/spring-hibernatetempate-example.html

Answer (score 2):

HibernateTemplate is the class of org.springframework.orm.hibernate3. HibernateTemplate provides the integration of hibernate and spring. Spring manages database connection DML, DDL etc commands by itself. HibernateTemplate has the methods like **save,update, delete** etc. 
Try to understand how to configure HibernateTemplate in our spring application.

**Add xml configuration in application.xml of spring application.**

```
<bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
<property name="sessionFactory">
  <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
</property>
```

hibernateTemplate will be used in the dao classes. Initialize hibernateTemplate. Provide a setter method to set hibernateTemplate by spring.

```
private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

public void setHibernateTemplate(HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate) {
    this.hibernateTemplate = hibernateTemplate;
}

public void persist(){
    User u1= new User(1,"Ankita");
    hibernateTemplate.save(u1);

    User u2= new User(2,"Renu");
    hibernateTemplate.save(u2);

}
```